# "Access Denied" error on Google Auth API for Calendar

Tags: asp.net, json, google-calendar-api, dotnetnuke, google-authentication

I have been trying since yesterdar to authenticate my requests to de Google Calendar V3 API in order to use it, but I am unable to pass through an AggregateException which contains just the text "Access Denied".

My conflictive code is this, being the last line the one who breaks:

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream =
            new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(credentialsPath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, writePath);

            var authTask = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
            );

            credential = authTask.Result;
        }
```

I have already tried recreating the secret key, generating the client_secret.json file again, creating another credentials... also I know that both paths, the JSON and the folder are correct, because I had to solve that before reaching this error.

Any hints on what can be the problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your DNN setup, you probably never configured your web site with correct user or IIS User permissions for the purpose of saving new data assets onto your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Access Denied" error is usually encountered due to [Invalid Credentials](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials).

Here are the suggested actions that you can try:

> - Get a new access token using the long-lived refresh token.
> - If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).
> - If you are seeing this for a service account, check that you have successfully completed all the steps in the [service account page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Hope that helps!